# How to read a particular PACF plot?

Tags: r, plot

I did SARIMA model for the first time. While reading articles and examples I didn't get how to examine ACF/PACF plots

After differencing my ts.data two times to get it stationary I saw that PACF plot and how no idea how to interpret it

Will be glad if someone could explain me that plot or/and give a good source to read about it [Differenced twice time series, lag is 12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSBY0.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to see both the ACF and the PACF at the same time to see if autocorrelation process of the series. Just seeing the PACF i think it might have a MA(1) because the first lag passes through the confidence interval, and then  the other are just a pattern. But to be sure have to see the ACF also